# Problems based on constrained motion and energy conservation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string, constrained-dynamics

[image]

Referring to qs no.47(Fig.20), we are asked to find the **M/m** ratio for the situation stated.Here's the solution to it-
[image]

[image]

(This is actually a question from the renowned S.S.Krotov problems book!).The solution seems fine to me,leaving out the *energy conservation* bit.Shouldn't the mass **m** have acquired a *rotational kinetic energy* when the block **M** is about to get separated from the mass **m** and rod? But they don't take it into account,and I don't get it. I may be wrong,but can someone show me where am I possibly going wrong, and why it isn't required at all to include the *rotational kinetic energy* of the mass **m**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the kinetic energy of the small body $m$ is its rotational kinetic energy(in this case)

here's how----

the  rotational kinetic energy is $\cfrac{I\omega^2}{2}$---1 where $I$ is moment of inertia of that small body in question

since its a small point mass its moment of inertia is $ml^2$ from figure about the hinge point ,since $\omega = \cfrac{v}{l}$ put this in 1 you will get rotational K.E= $\cfrac{mv^2}{2}$ which is same as its normal K.E (of $m$, no energy of rod is considered as its weightless)

since there is no translation motion of system $m$ and weightless rod ,so  rotational K.E= Normal K.E so we not need to treat them rotational K.E(they are same) separately in this case

*I  hope it helps. best of luck with Krotov and Irodov stuffs*

Comment: Yup that's what I thought at first, but shouldn't the position of centre of mass of the load 'm' be changing with time,so that it acquires a linear velocity forward, and thus a 'translational kinetic energy'?

Comment: no !!!, translation K.E means the axis  of whole system(rod + small mass) is translating with some velocity

Comment: Oh, I just forgot that the rod was hinged.You were right.Thanks a ton!

Comment: Such things bring about chain explosions, one confusion leads to another!

Comment: think it in simpler way , and see concepts carefully ( in sphere it rotates about center of mass, but the axis coincide with COM, but there could be whole complex systems where COM may not be axis) and krotov  would be in your back of your hand

Comment: Yeah those sound to me as familiar concepts.The problem arises when I get down to apply those!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because you are expected to interprete the mass as a **point mass**. Such approximation should be acceptable for a relatively small ball, since its inertia shrinks very steeply (i.e., I ~a^5) with its radius a, so that the rotational energy (~ I V^2/l^2; V being the velocity of its center) can be neglected compared to the translational energy(~ V^2 m), since the mass will not shrink so steeply (i.e., m ~a^3), and l >> a.

Comment: I hope you're right there, but such demanding situations are hard to notice, and it's really difficult(atleast for me!) to think just like the problem-composer when he was actually compiling those!I suppose it gets better as you get to solve more and more intriguing problems!

Comment: Sure, after a while you learn to associate those small circles to the desired assumptions automatically!